# Wicket's label location. html css

Tags: java, html, css, wicket

Good day everyone, I have a question about wicket's label. I know that I can easily make a label for a textfield:

```
<label class="form-label" wicket:for="date">
    <wicket:label>
    </wicket:label></label>
<input wicket:id="date" type="text" class="form-control">
```

And label appear above the  textfield. My question is: how can I locate label on different place within ability to see label changing color when textfield's validation failed, and to see nice messages in feedback? I have radio's and 
textfield below every radio button, would like to have an textfield's labels near radio buttons. Thanks!

Radio in java:

```
Radio dateType = new Radio<>("dateType", Model.of(OperationDateType.DATE));
```

radio in html:

```
<input wicket:id="dateType" type="radio">
```

I want something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <input wicket:id="dateType" type="radio">
  <label class="form-label" wicket:for="date">
  <wicket:label>
  </wicket:label></label>
</div>
<div class = "fg-form">
  <input wicket:id="date" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

But surely this is not how it works

Comment: Where the label gets displayed is really more a question of html/css style than a wicket question.

Comment: Can you more specific honestly i cant get it fully. You are trying to show error message on beside the components?

Comment: I'm trying to make textFiled's label located near radio, and want label still work like it located above textField(chnaging colour when validation fail and be able see error message with label's name on feedback)